# Phonegap 3.5 not compatible with phonegap build, how to downgrade?

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm new to phonegap and phone gap build. I've tried uploading a phonegap application to the phonegap build service, but it complains that phone gap 3.5 isn't supported. How do I downgrade to phonegap 3.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your `config.xml` and set `phonegap-version` to `3.4.0`:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.4.0"/>
```

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences